# Azure Devops Packer Build Agent (Define Vnet IP Range for the temporary Resource group which packer creates to take snapshot))

Tags: packer

I am trying to build a packer image on azure.  How do i Define Vnet and VM IP Ranges for Temporary packer Resource group(Which packer temporarily creates and destroys(Vnet,vm))to take a snapshot of the vm? I wanted to make sure that the default IP's Used by packer will not overlap with my exisiting IP's in the azure subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the options inside of your packer template to use an existing resource group and virtual network. See example below

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret": "ppppppp-pppp-pppp-pppp-ppppppppppp",
    "tenant_id": "zzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "subscription_id": "yyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyy",

    // These will allow you to select existing resources
    "build_resource_group_name": "my-existing-rg" // name of existing resource group
    "virtual_network_name": "my-existing-vnet" // name of existing vnet
    "virtual_network_subnet_name": "mySubnetName" // name of subnet inside vnet
    "private_virtual_network_with_public_ip": true // apply public IP to VM (optional)

    // Continue with rest of configuration
}
```

See https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html for reference